# How to hide multiple ID's when clicking on object - jQuery

Tags: jquery, object, hide, slidedown

So here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R47Jd/1/

My problem:
- I want the submenu (under work) and the content to hide when I click on the buttons next to work. 
- I also want **EVERYTHING** to hide when I click on "NICK POON PHOTOGRAPHY". This function only works when my submenu is hidden. How can I get this work? I know my code isn't really neat but it's my first time programming jQuery and I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate your time

---

This is the code:
**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#menu, ul#submenu, div#content").hide();
    $("h3").click(function () {
        if ( $( "ul#submenu" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {  
            $("ul#submenu").hide();
            if ( $( "ul#menu" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
                $( "ul#menu" ).slideDown( "slow" );
            } else {
                $( "div#content, ul#submenu, ul#menu" ).hide();
            }
        }
    });
    $("li#hoofdmenu").click(function () {
        if ( $( "ul#submenu" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
            $( "ul#submenu" ).slideDown( "slow" );
        } else {
            $( "ul#submenu, div#content" ).hide();
        }
    });

    $("a").click(function(event){
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $("div#content").show();
        $(url).show();              
        $(url).children().hide();   
        $(url).find("h1, p, li").slideDown(500)
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>Nick Poon photography</h3>
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="hoofdmenu">Work</li>
    <li><a href=".about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href=".news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href=".contact">Contact</a></li><br />
    <br />
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li><a href=".people">People</a></li>
            <li><a href=".objects">Objects</a></li>
            <li><a href=".series">Series</a></li>
        </ul>
</ul>

<div id="content">   
    <div class="about">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
        <h1>News</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.s</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display:inline;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this

```
 $("a").click(function (event) {
     var url = $(this).attr("href");
     $("#content").find("div").hide();
     $("div#content").show();
     $(url).show();
     $(url).children().hide();
     $(url).find("h1, p, li").slideDown(500)
     event.preventDefault();

 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R47Jd/6/)

**Edit**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul#menu, ul#submenu, div#content").hide();
    $("h3").click(function () {
        $("#menu").slideToggle();
        $("#content").hide();
    });
    $("li#hoofdmenu").click(function () {
        $("ul#submenu").slideToggle();
    });

    $("a").click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#content").find("div").hide();
        $("div#content").show();
        $(url).show();
        $(url).children().hide();
        $(url).find("h1, p, li").slideDown(500)
        event.preventDefault();

    });


});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R47Jd/13/)

Comment: @user3726162 please check now

Comment: @user2281280 Thank you for fixing the content. But I want EVERYTHING to hide when I click on "NICK POON PHOTOGRAPHY". (When **submenu**: People Objects Series is open)

Comment: @user2281280 OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH!! **I LOVE YOU**! You are amazing Anoop!

Comment: @ user2281280 Btw, can you make the submenu disappear when I click on "About News Contact"

Comment: @user2281280 http://jsfiddle.net/R47Jd/17/ It works, but I added some HTML for "People" but when you click on "People" the submenu disappears? :(

Comment: @user2281280 Thanks to your work I have fixed it! Look :D http://jsfiddle.net/R47Jd/22/ I'm so happy. You made my day!